# how to represent `n` as a series of numbers

Tags: list, variables, haskell, types

I have the following function:

```
type Coordin = (Int,Int)

data Grid = Open
          | Taken Int

myOwn :: Coordin -> Grid -> Bool
myOwn (x,y) grid  
    | ((board)!!(y)!!(x)) == Taken n           = True
    | otherwise                                = False
```

I would like `n` to mean any number (as `Int` is specified as such in Data Grid for that particular type) but the thing just won't work!! I thought about using a `where` clause but if there are any other ideas it would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With inspiration form camccann's solution:

```
type Board = [[Grid]]

isTaken :: Grid -> Bool
isTaken (Taken _) = True
isTaken Open      = False

myOwn :: Coordin -> Board -> Bool
myOwn (x,y) board = isTaken (board !! y !! x)
```

Comment: Any way to combine `isTaken` and `myOwn` into a single function?

Comment: @maclunian Yes, but it's nice to split things up into small functions.

Comment: @maclunian, Think twice my friend. What if you later need `isTaken` again? If you merge the two functions you won't have any `isTaken`. Now, Imagine you reuse `isTaken` a couple of times, and 3 months later you change `data Grid = ` to also include a constructor `ReTaken Int`. Then you must **update `isTaken` only at one place in your code**. This is modularity, and the reason why we love haskell. :)

Answer (score 3):

The expression after a guard is a boolean predicate, not a pattern binding. So you can't match `Taken n` with the computed value and bind a value to `n`.

Essentially, the guard is equivalent to this:

```
myOwn (x,y) grid = if board !! y !! x == Taken n
                   then True
                   else False
```

Aside from the superfluous `if` statement, it should be obvious that you can't bind `n` in this context.

To do what you're trying for, you'd need another pattern match:

```
myOwn (x,y) grid = case board !! y !! x of
                       Taken n -> True
                       ...
```

But, since you're not actually using the value of `n` here, you'd be better served by writing a separate function:

```
isTaken (Taken _) = True
isTaken Open = False
```

...then guarding with that, instead.

Incidentally, on a stylistic point, you have a lot of ugly superfluous parentheses in your guard expression; you should remove those.

Comment: Is there a way I could combine `isTaken` and `myOwn` into a single function?

Comment: @maclunian: You'd want to define `myOwn` using `isTaken`, most likely, as in what @Tarrasch wrote. But there's no reason to have a single definition because `isTaken` and indexing the grid are conceptually different operations, and it's more readable with `isTaken` separated out.

Answer (score 0):

```
myOwn (x,y) grid = not (board !! y !! x  == Open)
```

Comment: I hope you don't mind the critique, but while this answer isn't *fundamentally* wrong it's less than ideal. `Grid` has no `Eq` instance, and while it could be *given* one currently, it's unnecessary here. Imagine that a later refactoring adds a third constructor `PartlyTaken (Int -> Grid)` that defines what happens when adding something to a location; this prevents deriving `Eq`, but shouldn't prevent writing an `isOpen` predicate, just like `isNothing` doesn't need `Eq`. In summary, it's always better to avoid `(==)` when what you really want is case analysis.

Comment: I'm not sure why this was downvoted. It's not the best solution, but it still does what the function in the question was supposed to do in a reasonably straightforward fashion...